# Linq to Entities count not returning results

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq query that is producing the wrong sql (*ProductId = PictureId*). We just switched over to using Devart Entity Developer to auto-generate our POCO classes and this issue popped up. The mapping looks correct to me and this query returned the correct results previously. Does the mapping look wrong or perhaps the query itself was never correct?

Using Entity Framework 5.0.

**Query:**

```
var totalResults = _productRepository.Table.Where(a => a.Pictures.Any()).Count();
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[ProductPicture] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[PictureId] // this should be ProductId = ProductId
    )
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

**Fluent Mapping:**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Picture>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Products)
                .WithMany(c => c.Pictures)
            .Map(manyToMany => manyToMany
                .ToTable("ProductPicture", "dbo")
                .MapLeftKey("ProductId")
                .MapRightKey("PictureId"));
```

**Diagram:**

[image]

Comment: I would think the mapkey methods should be the other way around. Left key as PictureId and right key as ProductId?

Comment: Your right. I tried that before and it didn't work. After cleaning the solution and flipping them again it started working. Looks like Entity Developer's code generation script is just plain wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bug with association mapping in the DbContext template is fixed in the latest (5.7.276) build of Entity Developer: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=28723.